# php add class active to dropdown menu

Tags: php, if-statement

This is my code: I got the first and last "li" to work when $thisPage is on that page it add the class active. but for the drop down menu i am a little lost. I tried doing an array of the pages and a few other things but no luck.

```
<ul class="nav sf-menu">
    <li><a href="index.php" <?php if ($thisPage == 'index'){?> class="active"<?php }?>>Home</a></li>
    <li class="sub-menu"><a href="javascript:{}">About</a>          
      <ul>
        <li><a href="team.php"><span>--</span> The Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php"><span>--</span> About</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.php"><span>--</span> Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="testimonials.php"><span>--</span> Testimonials</a></li>
        <li><a href="timeline.php"><span>--</span> Timeline</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="gallery.php" <?php if ($thisPage == 'gallery'){?> class="active"<?php }?>>Gallery</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please write how you define a variable $thisPage.

Comment: Here you go Adam

$GlobalServer = "http://".basename($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])."/"; 
$GlobalPath = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']); 
$pathInfo = pathinfo(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']));
$thisPage = $pathInfo['filename'] ?>

Comment: Whats in `$thisPage`??

Comment: $thisPage = $pathInfo['filename'] ?>

Comment: I just need to be able to add the class="active" when any of the submenus of about is clicked. 
i got it working for the other ones but they re not submenus

Comment: @SergioWizenfeld See my answer below. Works with your menu structure (any number of levels)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use multiple `OR` conditions:

```
<li class="sub-menu"><a <?php echo ($thisPage == 'team' || $thisPage == 'about' || $thisPage == 'services' || $thisPage == 'testimonials' || $thisPage == 'timeline') ? 'class="active"' : ''?> href="javascript:{}">About</a>
```

Or preferably an array:

```
<?php $aboutPages = array('team','about','services','testimonials','timeline'); ?>
<li class="sub-menu"><a <?php echo in_array($thisPage,$aboutPages) ? 'class="active"' : ''?> href="javascript:{}">About</a>
```

Comment: Thank you man, this worked like a charm. I had something similar earlier but seeing you code i was messing up with the in_array

Answer (score 0):

An array is probably the way you should go here. Use a multidimensional array and iterate, see below. Using a function recursively allows for less / more robust code. This will work for you menu as well as a menu with many sub-levels.

```
$menu = array(
    'index'=>'Home',
    'about'=>array(
        'team'=>'The Team',
        'about'=>'About',
        'services'=>'Services',
        'testimonials'=>'Testimonials',
        'timeline'=>'Timeline'
    ),
    'gallery'=>'Gallery'
);

function create_menu($menu,$thisPage)
{
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($menu as $page=>$title)
    {
        if (is_array($title))
        {
            echo '<ul>';
            create_menu($title);
        }
        else
        {
            $active    = ($thisPage == $page) ? "active":"";
            echo  "<li><a class=\"$active\" href=\"{$page}.php\"><span>--</span> {$title}</a></li>";
            echo (count($menu) == $i) ? "</ul>":"";

            $i++;
        }
    }
}

// ehco'ing out in this example, but probably better to store in a variable before echoing
echo '<ul>';
create_menu($menu,'index'); // here you pass in $thisPage like so create_menu($menu,$thisPage);
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Thank you, I can see how this would work but having different classes makes it more difficult to use this method